# How to revert animation with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, revert, inverse

I'm wondering how to revert this animation using jQuery, look this page:

http://bksn.mx/TAC/

The correct way is when you click **"Equipo"**, it shows smooth animation and click this again, it reverts animation very well.

The incorrect way is when you click **"Arquitectura"**, it starts smooth animation, and click this again... it looks like messed up and doesn't revert animation...

I tried to make `.toggle();` methods but it didn't work 3 times, i had no idea why...

There is a script of **Arquitectura**:

```
$('h2#arq').click(function() {
  $('section#pryctA4, section#ext').animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    height: 'toggle',
    margin: 20
    }, {
    duration: 750,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear',
      height: 'easeInOutQuad'},
    }
  );
});
```

Another script of **"Equipo"** if you want:

```
$('h2#equipo').click(function() {
  $('section#team').animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    height: 'toggle'
    }, {
    duration: 750,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear',
      height: 'easeInOutQuad'},
    }
  );
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `margin` property isn't toggling (in animates *in* both times, giving the jerky effect):

```
$('h2#arq').click(function() {
  $('section#pryctA4, section#ext').animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    height: 'toggle',
    margin: 20},
{
    duration: 750,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear',
      height: 'easeInOutQuad'},
    }
  );
});
```

The dirty way to fix it is to include an inline `if`:

```
$('h2#arq').click(function() {
  $('section#pryctA4, section#ext').animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    height: 'toggle',
    margin: ($(this).css('margin') == 20) : 0 ? 20},
{
    duration: 750,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear',
      height: 'easeInOutQuad'},
    }
  );
});
```

Not sure if another more elegant solution exists.

Comment: I agree, but it is odd that the margin goes back to 0 when the animation starts.  I was looking at this to and in the jQuery examples, when if you tried to animate to a the margin width you were at nothing would happen.

Comment: Okay, the problem is twofold, margin is jerky because jQuery can't read 'margin' at the beginning.  You need to do one for each.

Comment: EDITed: Awesome! i'm going to test it

Comment: Well, it had conflict... look this it doesn't revert animation when you click #foo again.. Do you have an idea how to fix it? i'm sorry i'm not an expert http://jsfiddle.net/ec7KZ/2/ **EDIT: Oops, forget it, because i forgot to change selector at variable, it worked!**